# Bitrix Template customization

Tags: templates, customization, bitrix

We are using bitrix and we would like to customise the template of bitrix. 
Can any one help me how can we achieve it for ajax popup or template page.

Thanks
Ashish

Answer (score 3):

I am Bitrix developer from Russia.
You need use folder `\local\templates\` if this folder does not exist, then create it

You need copy some template from `\bitrix\templates\` in `\local\templates\`
[image]

go to the admin panel and the mood of the desired site the desired template

[image]

[image]

[image]

This will allow you to create a new template. but Bitrix has many standards. If you want to write good sites on Bitrix CMS then you need to know them.

Answer (score 0):

Templates are usually stored in

```
bitrix\templates\{some_template_name}
```

You can copy one, enable in admin panel and modify it according to your needs.
https://training.bitrix24.com/support/training/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=68&CHAPTER_ID=05984&LESSON_PATH=5936.5980.5984

Check how ajax functionality implemented in standard components and try it yourself. "socialnetwork" components are relatively new and probably best examples.
here is on of them:

```
bitrix/components/bitrix/socialnetwork.log.entry
```

Comment: Thanks Rafail, will it work for the same for telephony com.card.show template? I have customise it by modules/voximplant/ajax_hit.php, but I think that's not a correct way, so can we move modules/voximplant/ajax_hit.php on any other place?

Comment: /bitrix/modules/voximplant/ajax_hit.php is part of core files, it will be updated when you will update core files, so better to move your customization somewhere.

Comment: can you please suggest, where should it keep and how it can be call when any operation performed?

Comment: if you need it on any operation you can use "Event Handlers" like this (sorry in russian) https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/telephony/events/oncallstart.php in local/php_interface/ini.php

Comment: https://training.bitrix24.com/support/training/course/?COURSE_ID=68&LESSON_ID=6111&LESSON_PATH=5936.6078.6096.6109.6111 

I have tried above thread to customize socialnetwork_group.the list, it's worked fine. but now I want to customise voximplant.ivr.list component similarly but not able to find index.php file where I need to change my custom template path.
Would you please suggest what excitedly steps which I have to follow to customise these type of component

Comment: unfortunately I don't have b24 to check where this file is located. You can find where component is included by searching (grep) files in project dir for "bitrix:componentName" (in your case "voximplant.ivr.list")